# Amazon S3 service doesn't work with Plugin.Media from Xamarin PCL project

Tags: amazon-s3, xamarin.forms

I am trying to send uploaded image to Amazon S3 container from my Xamarin PCL project so that android and iOS work using this code  and here is my code:

```
private async void PickPhoto()
        {
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
                return;
            }
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            if (file == null)
                return;

            this.OrgLogo = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                return stream;
            });

            try
            {

                var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");
                var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
                var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);

                var filePath = file.Path;

                await transferUtility.UploadAsync(
                  filePath,
                  "xxx"
                );

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

But getting exception like below:

```
{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented in reference assembly.
at PCLCrypto.WinRTCrypto.get_HashAlgorithmProvider () [0x00000] in :0
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.HashingWrapper.Init (System.String algorithmName) [0x00016] in D:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util_pcl-sl\HashingWrapper.pcl.cs:42
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.HashingWrapper..ctor (System.String algorithmName) [0x00019] in D:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\HashingWrapper.cs:31
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.HashingWrapperMD5..ctor () [0x00000] in D:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util_pcl-sl\HashingWrapper.pcl.cs:116
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:644
```

Can anybody help me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem using the same exact plugins. It appears to be something with the windows version of the PCLCrytpo library. Since I wasn't concerned with the windows version I did the following:

1. Disabled (unloaded) the windows/ windows phone projects that are put there by default.
2. Cleaned the solution
3. Rebuilt the solution.

This seemed to solve my problem